# Kotlin: How to create a Flow of nothing

Tags: android, kotlin, generics, kotlin-flow, kotlin-nothing

I'm using a `Flow` just to communicate from the ViewModel with an activity, but I dont really need to pass any parameter to the activity. I just need the activity to react to the call.

Right now I have a flow of a nullable type:

`val myFlow: Flow<Nothing?> = someChannel.receiveAsFlow()`

And I need to emit a null, since `Nothing` cannot be instantiated:

`someChannel.send(null)`

What I'd like to do:

`val myFlow: Flow<Nothing>`

and then:

`someChannel.send()`

But of course that doesn't compile.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like mentioned in another answer, `Nothing` has a different purpose. You can also consider using `Unit` for that:

```
val myFlow: Flow<Unit> = someChannel.receiveAsFlow()
someChannel.send(Unit)
```

If you have a couple of places in the code where you call `someChannel.send(Unit)` you can create an extension function on `SendChannel` and call it instead of `someChannel.send(Unit)`:

```
suspend fun SendChannel<Unit>.send() = send(Unit)
```

And then just call:

```
someChannel.send()
```

Comment: I think it should be `suspend fun SendChannel<Unit>.sendNothing() = send(Unit)`. And you could create a non-suspending `trySendNothing()`. I think I would drop the word Nothing from the names because that makes their usage more verbose than directly calling `send(Unit)`.

Comment: Thanks @Tenfour04, you are right! `SendChannel<Unit>.send()` also sounds good.

Answer (score 2):

`Nothing` is intended for a different purpose.
From the kotlin [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-nothing.html):

> Nothing has no instances. You can use Nothing to represent "a value that never exists": for example, if a function has the return type of Nothing, it means that it never returns (always throws an exception).

But you try to emit a `null` value (it isn't `Nothing`). So, it looks like you are looking for a workaround where you really don't need it.

You can just create for example an `EmptyState` type and use it

```
val myFlow: Flow<EmptyState>
```